# How to select from a List<string[]>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List<string[]> called myList:

```
   [0] "ABC" "Item Description Here" "Item Code Here"
   [1] "DEF" "Item Description Here" "Item Code Here"
   [3] etc, etc...
```

This is how I populated myList:

```
...
while (myReader.Read())
{
   string[] row = new string[myInt];

   for (int i = 0; i < myInt; i++)
   {
      row[i] = myReader[i].ToString();
   }

myList.Add(row);    
}
...
```

Now I need to search through myList and return a new List<string[]> called newList[] that contains 1 or more string[] where the first string matches a keyword ("ABC", "DEF", etc). How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If you are searching only for one keyword:

```
var result = myList.Where(s=>s[0].Equals("\"ABC\"")).ToList();
```

2) If `checklist` contains same number of elements as `myList`:

```
List<string> checklist = new List<string>() {"ABC","DEF"};
var result = myList.Where((s,i)=>s[0].Equals(checklist[i])).ToList();
```

3) If it can match any keyword from a checklist than:

```
var result = myList.Where(s=>checklist.Contains(s[0])).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Define list of keywords:

```
var keywords = List<string>() {"ABC", "DEF", ...};
```

Then you can use LINQ to filter:

```
var newList = list.Where(ar => keywords.Contains(ar.First());
```

Or:

```
var newList = list.Where(ar => keywords.Any(k => k.Equals(ar.First()));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = myList.Where(s=> s.Length >= 1 && s[0].Equals("ABC")).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, Adrian... "Yo Adrian, I did it!" -Rocky Balboa